# Quasi-projective varieties bimeromorphic to quasi-Moishezon varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex smooth quasi-projective variety. Assume that there is a proper holomorphic map $f:X\to Y$ to a complex normal variety which is moreover bimeromorphic. Questions:

1. Can we conclude that $Y$ is a Zariski open set of a Moishezon variety $\overline{Y}$?
2. If 1 is too strong, can we prove that there exists a closed algebraic subvariety $Z$ of $X$ such that $f|_{X\backslash Z}$ is an isomorphism onto its image.

The first question can be seen as a motivation for the definition of quasi-Moishezon variety: a complex variety is quasi-Moishezon if it is a Zariski open set of a Moishezon variety.

Comment: That can fail if $Y$ is not normal, e.g., by glueing together pairs of points that accumulate somewhere on the "boundary" $\overline{X}\setminus X$.  My intuition suggests that this is true when $Y$ is normal by associating to $f$ the ideal sheaf of the fiber product $X\times_Y X$ as a closed subscheme of $X\times \overline{X}$.  This defines a holomorphic map from $X$ to the algebraic stack of coherent sheaves on $\overline{X}$.  If this is algebraic, you are done: use the existence part of the valuative criteria to extend to a closed subscheme of $\overline{X}\times_Y \overline{X}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks so much for your answer! Could you write the details for the answer please?  I think that this problem is fundamental in complex algebraic geometry.

Comment: Actually, now I believe there are counterexamples obtained as blowdowns of the total space of a pencil of K3 surfaces along countably many $(-2)$ curves in distinct fibers that accumulate at one point in the base of the pencil (remove the fiber over that point to get a quasi-projective total space).

Comment: @JasonStarr Could you please write your example in the answer please?